# R = TypeError: `then` expected a Promise, received function () { [native code] }

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I tried to use ramda with observablehq

It is said here
https://observablehq.com/@itacirgabral/ramda

to do

```
R = require('ramda');
```

but this generates this error:

```
R = TypeError: `then` expected a Promise, received function () { [native code] }
```

Can't find any solution to solve it, any idea ?

Comment: This thread will help [issue](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/2751)

Comment: @CodeManiac thanks, I'll try

Comment: Which version of Ramda are you using? AFAIK, the latest version of Ramda renames `then` to `andThen`, which should resolve this issue. Which version of Ramda are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The addition of R.then in Ramda 0.26 made the R object a Promise-like object, and meant that Promise.resolve() will attempt to resolve it by calling the then() method. R is not a Promise, and to reassure JavaScript of this fact, R.then is renamed to R.andThen.

Please, try with this:

```
R = require('ramda@0.25.0/dist/ramda.min.js')
```

You can read about this issue in this link:
https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/2751.

Comment: @hipertavo Could you please explain the changes you made? That would be most helpful.

Comment: @Aimery,

Instead of using:

`R = require('ramda');`

I use:

    `R = require('ramda@0.25.0/dist/ramda.min.js')`

If you use the first option, in observablehq.com you will get this error:

   `R = TypeError: `then` expected a Promise, received function () { [native code] }`

Comment: @Bergi, this change avoid the error you get if you use `R = require('ramda');`

Comment: @hipertavo Surely your answer is supposed to solve the question, that's what one would guess an answer does. But how does this code avoid the error? Why require this particular version? And why do it with a weird `require` call instead of simply updating the dependency? Please [edit] to explain how you came to this answer.

Comment: Hi @Bergi! You can read about this issue in this link: https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/2751, and the fix in https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/2772.

(There was a problem in Ramda 0.26: _The addition of R.then in Ramda 0.26 made the R object
a Promise-like object, and meant that Promise.resolve() will attempt
to resolve it by calling the then() method. R is not a Promise, and
to reassure JavaScript of this fact, R.then is renamed to R.andThen._).

Edited.